# Printing mathematical series concisely in Raku

Tags: sequence, raku

Mathematical series, take for example the consecutive sequence represented here as an array:

```
my @seq = my $a=0, {++$a} ... *;
for @seq[^10].kv {state $f=0; ($^k < 4 or $^k > 7) ?? say "a$^k =  "  ~ $^v !! (say "..." if $f ne 1; $f=1) };
```

Prints:

```
a0 =  0
a1 =  1
a2 =  2
...

a8 =  8
a9 =  9
```

1- Is there a simple way to drop just the first element i.e. `a0 =   0` from the printed output?

2- Could this code be made more idiomatic?

Comment: @DanBron Thank you for the comment. I've just edited and elaborated on the the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## A barebones solution

Let's start with a very simple solution for printing a gist of a sequence. It doesn't deal with the specifics you've added to your question but it's a good starting point:

```
sub seq-range-gist ( @seq ) {
  my @pairs = @seq.pairs;
  join "\n", @pairs.head(3)».gist, '...', @pairs.tail(2)».gist
}
```

Unlike `.kv`, which converts its invocant into the form `key1, value1, key2, value2, key3, value3, ...`, i.e. 6 elements if its invocant contains 3 elements, `.pairs` converts its invocant into the form `key1 => value1, key2 => value2, key3 => value3, ...`.

I used `.pairs` instead of `.kv` partly because it meant I could just use `».gist` later on in the code to effortlessly get a nice `key1 => value1` display for each element. We'll modify that below but this is a good idiomatic start.

The `.head` and `.tail` calls are the idiomatic way to create small lists of the first and last N elements from an invocant list (provided it's not lazy; more about that in a mo).

Given this initial solution, `say seq-range-gist (0,1 ... Inf)[^10]` displays:

```
0 => 0
1 => 1
2 => 2
...
8 => 8
9 => 9
```

Next, we want to be able to "drop just the first element ... from the printed output". Unfortunately `say seq-range-gist (0,1 ... Inf)[1..9]` displays:

```
0 => 1
1 => 2
2 => 3
...
7 => 8
8 => 9
```

We want the number on the left of the `=>` to retain the numbering of the original sequence. To enable this we split the underlying sequence from the range that we want extracted. We add a second parameter/argument `@range`, and append `[@range]` to the second line of the sub:

```
sub seq-range-gist ( @seq, @range ) {
  my @pairs = @seq.pairs[@range];
```

Now we can write `say seq-range-gist (0,1 ... Inf), 1..9` to display:

```
1 => 1
2 => 2
3 => 3
...
8 => 8
9 => 9
```

In your question you used the format `aINDEX =  VALUE` rather than `INDEX => VALUE`. To allow customization of the gist, we add a third `&gist` routine parameter/argument and invoke that instead of the built in `.gist` method:

```
sub seq-range-gist ( @seq, @range, :&gist ) {
  my @pairs = @seq.pairs[@range];
  join "\n", @pairs.head(3)».&gist, '...', @pairs.tail(2)».&gist
}
```

Note how the "method" invocations in the body of `seq-range-gist` sub are now `.&gist`, not `.gist`. The syntax `.&foo` invokes a *sub* `&foo` (which is typically invoked by writing just `foo`), passing the invocant on the left of the `.` as a `$_` argument to the sub.

Note also that I've made the `&gist` parameter a named one by preceding it with a `:`.

So now `say seq-range-gist (0,1 ... Inf), 1..9, gist => { "a{.key} =  {.value}" }` displays:

```
a1 =  1
a2 =  2
a3 =  3
...
a8 =  8
a9 =  9
```

## Adding polish

The rest of this answer is bonus material for readers who care about polish.

`say seq-range-gist (0, 1, 2, 3), ^3` displays:

```
0 => 0
1 => 1
2 => 2
...
1 => 1
2 => 2
```

Oops. And even if there were more pairs than the head and tail combined, so at least we didn't get repeated lines, it'd still be pointless using the `head, ..., tail` approach to elide just one or two elements. Let's change the last statement in the sub body to eliminate these issues:

```
  join "\n",
    @pairs < $head + $tail + 3   # Of course, the 3 is a bit arbitrary
      ?? @pairs».&gist
      !! (@pairs.head($head)».&gist, '...', @pairs.tail($tail)».&gist)
```

Next, it would be nice if the sub did something useful if called without a range or gist. We can mostly fix that by giving the `@range` and `&gist` parameters suitable defaults:

```
sub seq-range-gist (
  @seq,
  @range = @seq.is-lazy ?? ^100 !! ^@seq,
  :&gist = { .gist }
) {
```

If `@seq` is *not* [lazy](https://docs.raku.org/routine/is-lazy), then `@range` defaults to the full range of `@seq`. If `@seq` is *infinite* (in which case it's also lazy), then the *upto 100* default is fine. But what if `@seq` is lazy but yields less than 100 defined values? To cover this case we append `.grep: *.value.defined` to the `@pairs` declaration:

```
  my @pairs = @seq.pairs[@range].grep: *.value.defined;
```

Another simple improvement would be optional head and tail parameters, leading to a final polished solution:

```
sub seq-range-gist (
  @seq,
  @range = @seq.is-lazy ?? ^100 !! ^@seq,
  :$head = 3,
  :$tail = 2,
  :&gist = { .gist }
) {
  my @pairs = @seq.pairs[@range].grep: *.value.defined;
  join "\n",
    @pairs <= $head + $tail + 2
      ?? @pairs».&gist
      !! (@pairs.head($head)».&gist, '...', @pairs.tail($tail)».&gist)
}
```

Comment: The minimal solution works quite fine and it's also decently idiomatic. In my solution I had to resort to a 'flag' variable to reckon with the `...` part causing it look more like a C program. So this answers both parts of my question, really. As for the 'comprehensive' solution, it looks a bit intimidating, really.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and accepting my answer @LarsMalmsteen. That said, I've entirely rewritten my answer and feel it's much better. I've dropped the 'comprehensive' solution -- I'd gone far off into the weeds with that! -- but I've also completely rewritten the "minimal solution" and accompanying explanation. I did so mostly for other later readers but you might get some value out of reading the new answer.

Answer (score 8):

This might be a bit more idiomatic:

```
my @seq = 0, *+1 ... *;
say @seq[^4], @seq[7..10]
```

You don't need to use a lexical variable within the sequence; either [`Whatever`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Whatever) or [placeholder variables](https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#index-entry-$$CIRCUMFLEX_ACCENT) can safely be used within sequences. Then you can simply select the elements of the sequence you want printed.
Which returns `«(0 1 2 3)(7 8 9 10)␤»`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The `whatever`operator is refreshening but the series / sequence output doesn't address the main issue. I'd like to print the series as they are seen on math texbooks, i.e. with `...` notation in between.

Answer (score 7):

You can skip the first N values on *any* `Iterable` or `Sequence` with `skip`:

```
for (^5).skip(3) {
    .say
}
# 3
# 4
```

If you don't specify a number, it will skip only one element.

Comment: The `skip` seems to remove just the ouput i.e. the element with the 0th index (a0) remains. I've tried `@seq:delete` and it just replaced the 0th element with `(Any)`

Comment: Indeed.  The `skip` will just act as if the skipped elements do not exist.  This may or may not be what you want  :-)

Comment: When I put the `skip` in between so that it reads: `for @seq[^10].skip(0).kv` it *literally* doesn't skip the 0th element and it doesn't matter if I give as the argument to `skip`1 or 2, it just distorts the out furthermore. I need a practical way to remove the 0th element from ground up.

Comment: Perhaps `for @seq[^10].kv.skip(2)` is what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes that does the job. Actually I tried putting the `skip`after the `.kv` but using arguments other than 2, so it didn't work. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: For the 2nd question: Instead of ` ($^k < 4 or $^k > 7)` `($^k == (4..7).none)` looks not so much conciser but more idiomatic.

Comment: Given that in this case $^k is an integer value, then you could consider that equivalent.  *I* wouldn't call that necessarily more idiomatic: you do *not* have to use all possible features of Raku all of the time  :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
my @seq = my $a=0, {++$a} ... *;

my \i = 0;
say( 'a' ~ (i+$_) Z=> (i+$_) ) for @seq[^5]; 

print "------\n";

my \j = 1;
say( 'a'.succ ~ (j+$_) Z=> (j+$_) ) for @seq[^5];
```

Output:

```
(a0 => 0)
(a1 => 1)
(a2 => 2)
(a3 => 3)
(a4 => 4)
------
(b1 => 1)
(b2 => 2)
(b3 => 3)
(b4 => 4)
(b5 => 5)
```

I recognize the above doesn't include your 'bespoke' `gist` ellipsis conditional (  `($^k < 4 or $^k > 7)` ), but you seem to have come up with a more elegant way of writing that in the comments. Still (if you don't want to use `skip`), number keys yourself and include an offset such as `i` or `j` indicating how many elements of `@seq` you wish to skip.

Addendum: Below is an attempt at implementing your 'bespoke' `gist` ellipsis conditional (using `grep`):

```
my @seq = my $a=0, {++$a} ... *;
my \i = 0; my \m = 4; my \n = 7;

do for @seq[^10].grep({4 > $_ or $_ > 7 }) {
  say 'a' ~ (i+$_) Z=> (i+$_); 
  if  $_ == 3 {print "...\n"};
}
```

Output when `\i = 0`:

```
(a0 => 0)
(a1 => 1)
(a2 => 2)
(a3 => 3)
...
(a8 => 8)
(a9 => 9)
```

Output when `\i = 1`:

```
(a1 => 1)
(a2 => 2)
(a3 => 3)
(a4 => 4)
...
(a9 => 9)
(a10 => 10)
```